# bad argument 'PREROUTING'

Tags: port-forwarding

setting up Home Assistant on UBUNTU virtual machine. Trying to forward port from gateway to virtual machine. I need to put the IP in range of the rest of my network. In terminal:

```
iptables -t -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to [address here]
```

I'm getting a "bad argument" for PREROUTING and Google is not helping.
Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't specify the actual table after the `-t` directive. I suspect you mean `nat`. So `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to [address here]`. If it were me, I would also specify the network interface, so: `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i IF-NAME `--dport 80 -j DNAT --to [address here]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not getting any more errors but still can't connect to the virtual machine from Windows. It should be porting outside traffic through UBUNTU so I can reach the virtual machine.

Comment: I had assumed your iptables rule was entered on an Ubuntu computer host that also has an Ubuntu computer quest VM. Please describe your setup in more detail, including which hypervisor. Perhaps you could just put the VM directly on the host LAN. We might need to see your entire iptables rule set for context, but not sure depending on the more detail. That would be: `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL`